# ckeditor adding html tags in database

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I added ckeditor to my web admin panel

```
<textarea name="stateinformation" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>
<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    //CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        on: {
            instanceReady: function( ev ) {
                // Output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>.
                this.dataProcessor.writer.setRules( 'p', {
                    indent: false,
                    breakBeforeOpen: true,
                    breakAfterOpen: false,
                    breakBeforeClose: false,
                    breakAfterClose: true
                });
            }
}
});
</script>
```

I tried to make few para and bullet list. but the data that is being added to database looks something like this

```
<p>text...</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>text...</p><ul><li>text...</li><li>text...</li><li>text...</li></ul>
```

I tried using str_replace and stripslashes but it is also removing the para and bullet list effect. can anyone tell how to remove these special character without removing their effect

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Can-I-get-editors-data-plain-text-format. `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getText()`

Comment: @Tushar the link u have given is not working. And where should i place your code to test

Comment: Does it mean that you tried to give html markup data in your editor?

Answer (score 0):

Put the tags you want to allow in Ckeditor config file: for example

```
config.allowedContent =
    'h1 h2 h3 p blockquote strong em;' +
    'a[!href];' +
    'img(left,right)[!src,alt,width,height];';
```

And Refer [Advanced Content Filter(ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) for more help and examples